# Remove document if timestamp is too old

Tags: mongodb

I know there is possible to remove some documents when the saved date is passed away with this command:

```
db.course.deleteMany({date: {"$lt": ISODate()}})
```

I trying to do the same thing but I'm trying to check is a timestamps is passed away

All saved timestamps are like this one

```
1492466400000
```

Is it possible to make a command with a condition to delete all documents with a too old timestamp?

**EDIT**

I use milliseconds timestamps

Comment: What do you mean by *too old timestamp*? Do you have a given value?

Comment: @Styvane for example, this timestamp `1479464200000` (18 november 2016) is an old one but `1480933000000` (05 december 2016) is a good one. If the given timestamp is equal to an older date than the current date, it's an old one

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB you 3.2 you can also use TTL Indexes where you can say to MongoDB "please remove all the Documents if the {fieldDate} is more older then 3600 seconds". This is pretty useful for Logging (remove all logs more older then 3 months).

Maybe is not your use case, but I think is pretty good to know.

TL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time. Data expiration is useful for certain types of information like machine generated event data, logs, and session information that only need to persist in a database for a finite amount of time.

```
db.eventlog.createIndex( { "lastModifiedDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-ttl/

Comment: I don't think TTL would work if the thing field you are adding the index to is anything other then a Date() type. I had a similar case where a field call timestamp was a number and the ttl did nothing. Just a heads up to anyone in similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I find the way to do this

```
db.course.deleteMany({date: {"$lt": ISODate()*1}})
```

`ISODate()*1` condition will convert the Date into a timestamp

and

`ISODate(timestamp)` convert the timestamps into a Date.